# how Flask Create dependent dropdown list from API stream

Tags: python, list, flask, dropdown

I want to create two dependent drop down lists , the first has static content like Stake_Currency

```
stake_symbol = ('USDT','BNB','ETH','BTC') # content of the first drop down list where I can choose
```

the 2nd drop down list should be created on the fly from API Stream :

```
for  symbol in trade_symbol:
    if stake_symbol in symbol:
    print (symbol)
#here I will get all symbols , so if I choose USDT I will get all USDT pairs , and son on
```

most answers I found involve using database and ajax ,